# Cron not working on migrated site

Tags: 6, migrations, cron

After migrating a site, I checked /admin/reports/status and verified that cron has not been executed in a long time.

I tried to run cron manually /admin/reports/status/run-cron, but all I got was a blank page.

The file permissions for cron.php are 544
On the dblog page, I see this error 
"Cron run exceeded the time limit and was aborted."

Am I missing something else?

Comment: You need to up the script timeout in your PHP settings

Comment: Did you check your log? Any error showing there?

Comment: ^to add to @clive's comment above, if you can't increase the script timeout value, often times I've seen d6 sites bog down in clearing out tons of old caches so clearing them manually may help out in getting this kickstarted